# How to use cookies in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want use  cookies  that  copy from my chrome, but make much error.

```
import urllib.request
import  re

def  open_url(url):
header={"User-Agent":r'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}
Cookies={'Cookie':r"xxxxx"}
Request=urllib.request.Request(url=url,headers=Cookies)
response=urllib.request.urlopen(Request,timeout=100)
return  response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Where does my code go wrong? Is that headers=Cookies ?

Comment: the cookie isn't the headers. So don't pass it as that. You need to look at the cookiejar module most probably. It's not trivial though, so the easiest way is undoubtedly to use requests.

Comment: It's not a bad attempt; Let me strongly encourage using a higher level library, the norm is `requests` for synchronous code. Aaalso, how come `header` variable is unused? Did you intend to build a header that has both `User-Agent` and `Cookie` fields? Finally, I recommend experimenting with from command line with `httpie` first.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way when using urllib.request is to use an `OpenerDirector` populated with a`CookieProcessor`:

```
cookieProcessor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieProcessor)
```

then you use `opener` and it will automagically process the cookies:

```
response = opener.open(request,timeout=100)
```

By default, the CookieJar (`http.cookiejar.CookieJar`) used in a simple in memory store, but you can use a `FileCookieJar` in you need long term storage of persistent cookies, or even a `http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar` if you want to use persistent cookies stored in a `cookies.txt` now legacy Mozilla format

---

If you want to use cookies existing in your web browser, you must first store them in a cookie.txt compatible file and load them in a MozillaCookieJar. For Mozilla, you can find an add-on [Cookie Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-exporter/). For other browser, you must manually create a cookie.txt file by reading the content of the cookies you need in your browser. The format can be found in [The Unofficial Cookie FAQ](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5). Extracts:

> ... each line contains one name-value pair. An example cookies.txt file may have an entry that looks like this:
>
> .netscape.com TRUE / FALSE 946684799 NETSCAPE_ID 100103
>
> Each line represents a single piece of stored information. A tab is inserted between each of the fields.
>
> From left-to-right, here is what each field represents:
>
> - domain - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.
> - flag - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the browser, depending on the value you set for domain.
> - path - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for.
> - secure - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is needed to access the variable.
>     *expiration - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
> - name - The name of the variable.
> - value - The value of the variable.

But the *normal* way is to mimic a full session and extract automatically the cookies from the responses.

Comment: if I  want use cookies  that copy from my  web browser， what should  i do?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a better library (IMHO) - `requests`.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
}

cookies = dict(c1="cookie_numba_one")

r = requests.get('http://example.com', headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score -2):

"When receiving an HTTP request, a server can send a Set-Cookie header with the response. The cookie is usually stored by the browser and, afterwards, the cookie value is sent along with every request made to the same server as the content of a Cookie HTTP header" extracted from mozilla site.

This link
[Please go through this](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.cookies.html)
will help you give some knowledge about headers and http request. Please go through this. This might answer alot of your answer.